# Python - How can linalg.eigsh find *all* the eigenvectors?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I am using the example code on the documenation page for `linalg.eigsh`, [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh):

```
import scipy.sparse.linalg as sp
import numpy as np

id = np.eye(13)
vals, vecs = sp.eigsh(id, k=6)

len(vals)
# 6
len(vecs)
# 13
```

I am asking it for `6` eigenvalues (`k=6`) and it does return 6, but it gives me 13 (i.e. **all**) the eigenvectors. 
 In the documentation, right when it talks about `k`, it says:

> The number of eigenvalues and eigenvectors desired. k must be smaller
>   than N. It is not possible to compute all eigenvectors of a matrix.

And indeed I thought that the speed of the Lanczos method, underlying `eighsh` was due to it finding only a subset of the eigvectors.

So how can it return all the eigenvectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're interpreting the results wrong. The eigenvectors are the *columns* of `vecs`, but you're counting the rows. `vecs` has six columns, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It's not; vecs is a 13 x 6 matrix. The eigenvector n is:

```
vecs[:, n]
```